# Using meta tables to determine if a field in a record has a default value/

Tags: sql, peoplesoft

How can you determine the default value of a Record Field using a query? or a meta table? I can't seem to find a way for such.

Thanks for any help guys.

Comment: `SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_DEFAULT FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ABC'`

Comment: Is USER_TAB_COLUMNS an existing record in PeopleSoft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That information is stored in PSRECFIELD. The fields of interest are DEFRECNAME AND DEFFIELDNAME. If you have a constant default, the value will be in DEFFIELDNAME. If you are pulling the value from another record, then both will be populated.

```
SELECT RECNAME, FIELDNAME, DEFRECNAME, DEFFIELDNAME FROM PSRECFIELD WHERE RECNAME = :1 AND DEFFIELDNAME <> ' ';
```

Comment: how will you know if a field does need a default value?

Comment: Sorry, what do mean by "a field does need a default value"? PS will add the default value for the field if one is not given when a row inserted.

Comment: Its all clear now man, just wanted to check if there is a way for us to query if a certain field needed a default value beforehand.